# Sobre-Escritura de datos

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Estoy llenando una tabla de html con datos que me arroja una consulta con ajax. El llamado lo inicializa un select dependiendo del dato seleccionado:

```
 <select name="verListaDe"  class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <option id="all" value="1">Todos</option>
        <option id="prof" value="3">Profesores</option>
</select>
```

y el código en ajax tengo lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var screen = $('#loading-screen');
configureLoadingScreen(screen);

$('#prof').on('click', function(){
     $.get('../listaEmpleado/profesores/3')
         .done(function(result){
             $.ajax({
        url:'../listaEmpleado/profesores/3',
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {

        },
        success:function(data){

       $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {           

            $('#contenido').append("<tr><td><center><img style='width: 100px; height: 100px'  class='img-thumbnail' src='../img/"+opt.foto+"'></img></center></td>"
                +"<td>" +opt.NombreEmpleado+" "+opt.txtPaterno+" "+opt.txtMaterno+ "</td>"
                +"<td>Profesor</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.cedulaProfecional+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.especialidad+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.nivelEstudios+"</td>"
                +"<td><a href='../edit/profesor/" +opt.id+ "'<button class='btn btn-info'>Editar</button></a>"
                +" "+"<a href='../delete/profe/" +opt.id+ "'<button class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button></a></td></tr>"); 


            });
        }
    });
         })
         .fail(function(error){
             console.error(error);
         })
})
});

function configureLoadingScreen(screen){
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        screen.fadeIn();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        screen.fadeOut();
    });
}



$(document).ready(function(){
var screen = $('#loading-screen');
configureLoadingScreen(screen);

$('#emp').on('click', function(){
     $.get('../listaEmpleado/general/1')
         .done(function(result){
             $.ajax({
        url:'../listaEmpleado/general/1',
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {

        },
        success:function(data){

       $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {           

            $('#contenido').append("<tr><td><center><img style='width: 100px; height: 100px'  class='img-thumbnail' src='../img/"+opt.foto+"'></img></center></td>"
                +"<td>" +opt.NombreEmpleado+" "+opt.txtPaterno+" "+opt.txtMaterno+ "</td>"
                +"<td>Profesor</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.cedulaProfecional+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.especialidad+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+opt.nivelEstudios+"</td>"
                +"<td><a href='../edit/profesor/" +opt.id+ "'<button class='btn btn-info'>Editar</button></a>"
                +" "+"<a href='../delete/profe/" +opt.id+ "'<button class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button></a></td></tr>");   
            });
            }
         });
             })
             .fail(function(error){
             console.error(error);
         })
})
});

function configureLoadingScreen(screen){
    $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        screen.fadeIn();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        screen.fadeOut();
    });
}
```

el código funciona el problema es que al seleccionar el mismo dato se vuelve a colocar (realiza la petición otra vez pero coloca de nuevo la información) y si selecciono otra opción trae la info nueva pero deja la info anterior. como lo puedo arreglar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. podrías usar esto antes de hacer el each para que limpie todo el contenido y poner el nuevo simplemente usa el `empty`.Ejemplo  $('#contenido').empty();

Answer (score 1):

Solo coloca esta línea entre estos dos para que antes de que vuelva a llenarla con los datos, borre lo que ya tiene.

```
success:function(data){
  $('#contenido').html('');//esta línea entre el success y eel each que agrega los datos, y listo.
   $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
```